# Escape sequence when adding multiple records to DerbyDB

Tags: java, sql, escaping, derby

I'm converting (or trying to) an Ms AccessDB into derby.

When I extract the data from certain varchar / text / memo field from access they are filled with apostrophe, and mathematical symbols (percent, less than etc), and possible foreign characters

I need to keep these and I test for them so as I can use an 'escape sequence' to ensure they get put into the database.

However for now I am unable to get the data into the DB without it failing on these fields. When the SQL fails I output the SQL string, and cut and past it into ij. Then I modify just the first record, and it is always these characters that cause me grief.

I've tried to modify the strings by surrounding with "double quote marks" but that just gives a different error (stating that it has 'enounterd """ at line1 column x' which is always the first occurance of the double quote).

I haven't found a setting in derby to alter the behaviour for strings, yet. Is there one?

I have also tried to set the SQL statment to a preparedStatement then use the {call preparedStatement} again this fails also. I can't use the {escape "escape char} in a normal statment as derby just says incorrect syntax at me.

How do others manage to get user content with strange characters into a field in derby?
Do I need to change my field into a CLOB or something other than varchar / long Varchar?
Are my problems being caused by using the wrong characteset (eg iso rather UTF-8), how do I tell what it is, how to change it?

Below is a sample of the SQL insert that fails when I send it to derby (via my JAVA 'programme')

> insert into S1.SORTIEDESSAI (OBS, DATEDUSORTIE, CONTREINDIC, FIN,
>   PDEVU, REFUS, INVDECISN, ADMIN, MOTIF_DE_LA_SORTIE, NOMVALIDEE,
>   DATEVALIDEE) values ('"0001/0001"' , '2007-07-15' , false , true ,
>   '"null"' , '"null"' , '"null"' , '"null"' , '"2.  FIN DE L’ESSAI"' ,
>   '"DR SIMON"' , '2011-04-19' )

Note:
Actually I look at the above and notice that the order of columns names isn't good? It was OK yesterday, not sure why it would have changed? something to do with Access returning the column names in a random order from the resultSetMetaData, which would be a surprise.

for now I recomend any further answers to hold off whilst I sort this problem out, OK solved that problem, do I need to set another question about this behaviour....
Back to the main thread...

Ok as you can see on my SQL statement I have wrapped any varchar fields in double quotes. This always fails (even directly through ij). help help help...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your question is, but in general you can input these characters by using a PreparedStatement of the form: INSERT INTO tablename (columnname) values (?), and then    using the PreparedStatement.setString() method to supply your character data for that column.

Comment: I'm effectively catching all the data from an MS Access table, then copying the table structure, and inserting the data, I've eddited my answer to include a sample of the insert statement... D

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment initially. Are you proposing that I create a prepared statament, then insert records one at a time as I get them prepared... if so fair enough, but why can't I insert those characters with a normal statement, and escape them somehow?

Comment: I think you *can* insert those characters with a normal statement, and escape them. You can see Derby's rules for those strings here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqlj28468.html Note that you should be using single quotes for your character strings, not double quotes. I was mostly suggesting you might find it easier to avoid those issues by using parameter substitution instead.